# problems showing only projects that belong to a user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I am building a rails app where you can display projects and so on and so forth. I have the following code in my projects controller:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.create(params[:project].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    if @project.save
      redirect_to project_path(@project), :flash => {:success => 'We have created your project'}
    else
      redirect_to :back, :flash => {:error => 'Cannot allow an empty project name'}
    end
  end
```

this will create a project, from what I understand based on and related to the id of the user, in the model I have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_title, :user_id

  has_many :categories, :order => 'position', :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tasks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :discussions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users

  belongs_to :user

  validates :project_title, :presence => true
end
```

**Updated: The User Controller Show Action to show the projects for the user**

```
  def show
    @user = current_user

    @projects = current_user.projects.all
    @tasks = current_user.tasks.all
    @categories = current_user.categories.all
    @discussions = current_user.discussions.all
  end
```

**Updated to show projects controller index action **

```
  def index
    @project  = Project.new
    @projects = Project.all
  end
```

With that in mind I am wondering why it is I can have a user bob create a project, log out and user jake can log in and see user bobs project...

am I doing something wrong on the create? I can show more code if you need, but I thought this would be most useful.

Comment: What does your show action look like?

Comment: Scott S is right, you should look the action, see that you call the projects over an object and not over the class...

Comment: updated to show the user show action. I hope that helps

Comment: Could it be the index action that you're viewing? Please post the code to your index action (if it exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in  your `index` method of `users_controller`, you are fetching all the projects created. If you want to display projects created by current_user only, you should only fetch those records.

i.e. It should be

```
       @projects = current_user.projects
```

and what you have at the moment is (may be)

```
       @projects = Projects.all
```

Also in your show method above doing current_user.projects`.all` doensn't make any sense.

`current_user.projects` will fetch the records you need.

Comment: I updated the original post. to show the show method of what I have for the users show