# undefined projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So yesterday I asked a question about getting the projects for a current user. Well I ran into an issue. [See that thread here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13497912/problems-showing-only-projects-that-belong-to-a-user) So today I was working on displaying categories and tasks for the user along with any discussions. when I loaded up the page to view this I got:

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#show

undefined method `projects' for #<User:0xad5823f4>
Rails.root: /home/adam/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/StartPoint

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"4"}
```

This is currently whats in my users#show method:

```
  def show
    @projects = current_user.projects
    @tasks = current_user.tasks
    @categories = current_user.categories
    @discussions = current_user.discussions
  end
```

the table names are projects, tasks, categories and discussions. I have no problem using this any where else so why am I seeing this error?

if you need more code I can show it. the error is pretty clear but again I use this type of call else where to display project specific information such as a projects categories or tasks. could it be something with my relationship between a user and categories, discussions, tasks and so on? because I do have user_id in each table that is listed in the show method, among others.

Also I thought of this, this morning since were on this topic: current_user seems wrong because if I click on Bobs profile I will see all my stuff no? should it not be something more specific to the users id?

Comment: Can you post your `Project` model? At least the first lines

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time. Asking multiple questions results in a very confusing series of comments and answers, making the overall question very unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you established the association in each model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
```

Also be sure that `current_user` is actually a User object and not some thin proxy.

Generally you need to distinguish between the session user and the displayed user. This is why names like `current_user` are harmful. I'd recommend using `session_user` to refer to the logged in user and `@user` to refer to the user being displayed.

Some login systems define only a `current_user` method, but to alias this isn't hard. It's just defective by design in that case.

Comment: so is there examples of how to display some one elses profile as opposed to mine?

Comment: Replace `current_user` with `@user` and make sure that instance variable is assigned in advance.